# Trying to get Package Version Information to display in an "About" message

Tags: android

I have been struggling with getting the versionName for a running application from the PackageInfo Object type.

I have constructed a Parcelable Interface with all of the fields associated with the PackageInfo Object type.  The primary input for that interface method is a Parcel object.

I cannot seem to figure out how to correctly associate these Parcelable, Parcel, and PackageInfo objects.

Is there any sample code out there that I can look at?  Doesn't seem like it should be that difficult but it seems to be stumping me.

Thanks
Jazz

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense to me.  What does the package information have to do with Parcels?

Comment: PackageInfo (only runtime source of build version I could find)  implements a Parcelable object.  The only way that I have been able to find to deal with an Parcelable object is to build an interface that requires a Parcel object to run.

I would be tickled pink if I didn't need to deal with a Parcel.

Answer (score 46):

Sample code:

```
try {
    PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
    return packageInfo.versionName;
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    //Handle exception
}
```

Comment: Does this require any privileges?

Answer (score 11):

**Modern way:**

If you build your Android project by Gradle (with Android Studio), there is a best shortcut to get version:

```
com.yourproject.BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME
```

It's linked to `versionName` in your `build.gradle` file.

In fact, you can get Application ID, and more information from your `build.gradle` file by this way.

Comment: or in short BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME, if you are in same package.

Comment: note, this is a bit volatile in a project with multiple modules since only the app module has the right Version Name and Code.

Comment: Does not seem to work for android library modules.

Answer (score 8):

I use the following code to get the version used in the manifest. I wrote a small function to encapsulate and hide this somewhat big chunk needed to just get an int.

```
private int getVersion() {
    int version = -1;
    try {
        PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        version = pInfo.versionCode;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Name not found", e1);
    }
    return version;
}
```

This will return the int chosen to identify your version in the market (VersionCode). Not the VersionName. To see how to change to code for this have a look at the code from Casebash.

Answer (score 4):

`PackageInfo`'s `versionName` is a public data member. You do not need to do anything special to get "the versionName for a running application from the PackageInfo Object type". If you have a `PackageInfo` object named `info`, you access `versionName` via `info.versionName`.

Answer (score -4):

Also there is a shortcut:

`String version = new PackageInfo().versionName;`