# Retrieve the app package and version in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm implementing an error report system in my app,

how can I retrieve programmatically the package of my app and its version?

Thanks

Comment: Are you aware of ACRA? It may already do what you want. http://code.google.com/p/acra/

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll check it for the error report anyway I need the app version for checking the app updates

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610473/trying-to-get-package-version-information-to-display-in-an-about-message

Answer (score 5):

The PackageInfo class has a versionCode field that will give you the version, the versionName field will give you the version name, and packageName that will give you the package name. Context will give you a PackageManger instance that will give you a PackageInfo instance.

```
String packageName = "exampleApp";
try {
    PackageInfo pi = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    int versionNumber = pi.versionCode;
    String versionName = pi.versionName;
    String packageName = pi.packageName;
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following:

```
Context.getApplicationContext.getApplicationInfo().packageName;
```

This returns a string.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can also get the version from this info Object.

Comment: I didn't find that, Phil.  Add a comment here, and I will edit my post.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the PackageManager class.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/package-summary.html