# Check if a certain applications is installed and get it's version

Tags: android

I need to check if a certain application is installed (I know what it is by its package name "com.domain.appname"), and if it's not installed show a toast message. If it's installed, I need to get its version and show a toast message with its version.
Is it possible?

The other question ([How to get a list of installed android applications and pick one to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run)) doesn't mention getting the version.

Comment: The linked question is to get a list of all applications while this question to get information about specific applications with known package names so I don't think the linked question is close enough.  That being said, it's a possible dup of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610473/trying-to-get-package-version-information-to-display-in-an-about-message

Comment: @MCeley I know that it is pretty hard to get an entry out of a list... so if someone asks on how to set the text color to white you wouldn't mark it duplicated with one asking for blue?

Comment: @WarrenFaith Alright, you got me on that one.  I just thought the question I linked was a bit closer to what the poster was asking.

Comment: Well I had to choose one out of many :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get that information from the PackageManager.

```
private String getVersionName(String packageName) {
    String version = null;
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        version = pInfo.versionName;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return version;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfect (sorry for duplicate, but the code of the other posts doesn't works) Thanks again :)